# Why is this extension method not working?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

```
public static string ToTrimmedString(this DataRow row, string columnName)
{
    return row[columnName].ToString().Trim();
}
```

Compiles fine but it doesn't show up in intellisense of the DataRow...

Comment: shows in intellisense in my VS10. just tested it.

Comment: Please post the incomplete line where you are trying to call the extension method.

Comment: Also: be careful, if the `row` doesn't contain any column by the name of `columnName` you'll end up getting an exception - you might want to check for that and return `null` or an empty string if that's the case

Comment: @marc_s Absolutely, this was just for simplicity...

Comment: Extension methods should be define inside a static class.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My guess is you haven't included the namespace.

Comment: `using System.Data;` is included... Do you think it would compile if `using System.Data;` was not included?

Comment: The namespace of the class that has the extension method.

Comment: that could be it, the class from which I'm trying to use the method is a "sub" namespace of the namespace the extension method is in... will accept if that turns out to be the issue... thanks for clarification...

Answer (score 11):

Ensure this method is in a `static class` of its own, separate class from the consuming DataRow.

```
namespace MyProject.Extensions
{
   public static class DataRowExtensions
   {
      //your extension methods
   }
}
```

In your consumer, ensure you're:

```
using MyProject.Extensions
```

Comment: I don't think it would compile if it weren't in a static class

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. My mistake wasn't that I missed the static class or static method but that the class my extensions were on was not public.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a missing using, following case with the same symptom may occur:
If you are inside a method of the class itself (or one if its implementors / inheritors), you need to make use of `this`.

File extension.cs:

```
namespace a 
{
    public static void AExt(this A a) {}
}
```

File user.cs

```
namespace a 
{

    class A {}

    class B : A 
    {
        this.AExt();
        // AExt() will not work without this.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different namespaces try this code.

```
namespace Extensions
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsNumeric(this string inputString)
        {
            return decimal.TryParse(inputString, out decimal result);
        }
    }
}

namespace Business
{

    // add here other namespaces
    using Extensions;
    public static class Tools
    {
        public static bool Check(string inputString)
        {
            return inputString.IsNumeric();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue. My mistake is the argument type is not same: defined one is Session, revokded one is ISession.